# How do I create a new instance of a control in the view without violating MVVM

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I am encountering a similar problem to what is described [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904341/silverlight-oob-webbrowser-exception). The suggested solution is to create a new WebBrowser Control for each now page (PDF) we wish to present (Overwriting the old WebBrowser control).
What is the correct way of creating a new control like that in MVVM? I trying to keep the VM ignorant about the implementation of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does the VM need to know? Why can't the view just hook into an appropriate event (define one if you like, or just use the `PropertyChanged`) and recreate the control?

Comment: Yeah, that's what MVVM really is about. I would add another idea proving correctness of this approach. If at some moment of time the OP decides that he/she needs the content to be shown in a panel, or in a window or whatever else instead of a `WebBrowser`, the only thing to be changed will be the tiny piece of code in the view that decides how to show that content. VM remains intact.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an interface in the ViewModel named IBrowserCreator, with a method called CreateBrowser().
2. Create a static class in the ViewModel named ViewHelper, and add to it a static property of type IBrowserCreator named BrowserCreator.
3. In the View layer, create a new class called BrowserCreator, which implements ViewModel.IBrowserCreator.
4. In the View initialization code, instantiate a BrowserCreator, and assign it to ViewModel.ViewHelper.BrowserCreator.

From your ViewModel, you should now be able to call:

`ViewHelper.BrowserCreator.CreateBrowser()`

Obviously this answer is a framework only, but it should give you the general idea. You'll need to implement the CreateBrowser method to suit your exact needs.

Comment: Thanks! I really like this solution, but I missed the simpler approach that Kent Boogaart suggests, and is possible in my case.

Comment: What I really don't like in this solution is having a static property. What if there are several instances of VM and V simultaneously? The solution may be appropriate in some cases, but I would not recommend it. Kent Boogaart's way is both simpler and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply use a Datatemplate and let WPF do the rest?

1. create a usercontrol with the webbrowser. you have to add an attached property because you can not bind to source directly.

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="WpfBrowser.BrowserControl"
            xmlns:WpfBrowser="clr-namespace:WpfBrowser" >
     <Grid>
       <WebBrowser WpfBrowser:WebBrowserUtility.BindableSource="{Binding MyPdf}"/>
     </Grid>
   </UserControl>
   ```
2. create a viewmodel which handle your uri

   ```
   public class MyPdfVM
   {
     public Uri MyPdf { get; set; }

     public MyPdfVM()
     {
       this.MyPdf = new Uri(@"mypdf path"); 
     }
   }
   ```
3. take your pageviewmodel, add the pdfviewmodel and take a contentcontrol in your view

   ```
   public class MyPageViewmodel: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
     private MyPdfVM _myPdfStuff;
     public MyPdfVM MyPdfStuff
     {
       get { return _myPdfStuff; }
       set { _myPdfStuff = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged(()=>this.MyPdfStuff);}
     }

     public MyViewmodel()
     {
       this.MyPdfStuff = new MyPdfVM();
     }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     protected void NotifyPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
     {
       var propertyInfo = ((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member as PropertyInfo;

       if (propertyInfo == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentException("The lambda expression 'property' should point to a valid Property");
       }

       var handler = PropertyChanged;

       if (handler != null)
           handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyInfo.Name));
     }
   }
   ```

window.xaml

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfBrowser.MainWindow"
            xmlns:WpfBrowser="clr-namespace:WpfBrowser" 
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
     <Window.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfBrowser:MyPdfVM}">
        <WpfBrowser:BrowserControl />
       </DataTemplate>
     </Window.Resources>
     <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="64*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="247*" />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,14,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
      <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding MyPdfStuff}"/>
     </Grid>
    </Window>
```

window.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MyViewmodel _data;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        _data = new MyViewmodel();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = _data;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._data.MyPdfStuff = new MyPdfVM() { MyPdf = new Uri(@"your other pdf path for testing") };
    }
}
```

when ever you change the MyPdfStuff Property the webbroswer update the pdf.

attached property

```
public static class WebBrowserUtility
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableSource", typeof(string), typeof(WebBrowserUtility), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, BindableSourcePropertyChanged));

    public static string GetBindableSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(BindableSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBindableSource(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BindableSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static void BindableSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = o as WebBrowser;
        if (browser != null)
        {
            string uri = e.NewValue as string;
            browser.Source = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri) ? null:new Uri(uri);
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: added some code so you can see that if you chane the PDFViewmodel your browsercontrol show the new pdf.

Comment: This does not work. Browser throws an exception when changing the URL. Please see the other SO question I referenced.

Comment: it does work like a charme. i will add some code so you can try your self.